# How to remove extra timestamp added by logstash for syslog output plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, rsyslog

I am using logstash pipeline to ingest data into rsyslog server .

But the pipeline is adding extra time stamp  at the beginning.

Sample message:

**Sep 22 04:47:20**  22-09-2022 05:47:20.875 a7bd0ebd9101-SLOT0   `TEST-AWS-ACTIVITY`#011970507     P        201059147698 `[FCH-TEST] [35.49.122.49] [TEST-251047********-******] [c713fcf9-6e73-4627-ace9-170e6c72fac5] OUT;P;201059147698;;;;/bcl/test/survey/checkSurveyEligibility.json;ErrorMsg=none;;{"body":{"eligible":false,"surveys":[]},"header":null}`

But I am not getting a configuration to remove the timestamp from output.

The timestamp is already present as part of the message and that is all I need to show .

The data is coming from AWS cloudwatch installed on ECS containers.

The pipeline is configured as :

```
input  { pipeline { address => test_syslog } }

filter {

if [owner] == "1638134254521"  { 
   mutate { add_field  =>  { "[ec_part]" => "AWS_TEST"} }
  
  } 
}

    output {
    #TEST ACTIVITY Logs being sent via TCP to Logreceiver
      if [ec_part] == "AWS_TEST" {
      syslog {
        appname => ""
        sourcehost =>""
        host => "10.119.140.206"
        port => "10514"
        protocol => "ssl-tcp"
        ssl_cacert => "/etc/logstash/ca.crt"
        ssl_cert => "/etc/logstash/server.crt"
        ssl_key => "/etc/logstash/server.key"
        priority => "info"
        rfc => "rfc5424"
        codec => plain { format => "%{message}" }
      }
      }
    }
```

Comment: are you using grok pattern to pass this message ?

Comment: No I am not using any grok pattern . The logs are coming as it is from AWS cloud watch

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mutate filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html) from Logstash with `gsub` which will replace date in starting.

```
filter {
      mutate {
        gsub => [
          "message", "^\\w{3,4} \\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\s+", ""
        ]
      }
    }
```

**PS:** I have not tested this configuration but mostly this will work with minor change. You can update regex based on your requirement and data.

Comment: Hi ,  Thanks for your help ..But I doubt if it will work. As I understand the timestamp in the beginning is not comin from message but from the date filter plugin : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html . I am not getting way  to remove this configuration.

Comment: but where are you using date filter ? whatever you have given in yur question dont have date filter. did you not posted full pipeline configuration? If not then please do it.

Comment: I am not using this filter .But I guess this is getting used by default ..This is what the EsaaS documents mentions:      In the absence of this filter, logstash will choose a timestamp based on the first time it sees the event (at input time), if the timestamp is not already set in the event. For example, with file input, the timestamp is set to the time of each read.

Comment: Ok.. then also you can used same `gsub` to remove date from your message field. Also, as far as i know `date` filter will not update your `message` field but it will add new field in your document for date.

Comment: You can validate by running your logstash pipeline again and if `date` filter is adding that timestamp in starting of message field then it should show date of today for same message as it will consider `input time`.

Comment: Thats correct . But the requirement is to keep the date as it is  that is coming as part of the message . And remove the addtional date  which is being added by default by the date filter.

Comment: However I will aso try implimenting this mutate gsub and check

Comment: Sure. You can check that.